# Align Text Top with Sibling Element Background

Tags: css

*Ignore whether or not this actually looks good.*

I'm looking for the best way to align the top of text with an adjacent block element with a background or image in it. With the test-case snippet below, what I'm trying to [elegantly] get rid of is the red gap:

[image: Diagram showing unwanted space]

```css
.col {
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
.bg {
  background: #333;
}
p,h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col bg"></div>
<div class="col">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

This is essentially coming from the `line-height`. Setting `line-height` to 1 solves the problem but then borks any multi-line text which I need to support. Even applying the `line-height` change just to the `:first-line` results in bad spacing on multi-line text. Right now, the best I can think of is trying to come up with some magic-number negative `em` `margin-top` value to apply to headings, paragraphs, etc., but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer provided right now does work but I really wanted to avoid the extra markup required to make it work. Unfortunately that led me to a [magic number](http://css-tricks.com/magic-numbers-in-css/) solution. I'm not sure there's a good solution right now that's pure-CSS. I played with the :first-line pseudo selector but to ill effect.

What I ended up with was just using a negative `margin-top` on the `<h1>` element. I think the value of of the margin more or less works out to:

```
-(({line-height} - 1 ) / 2)em
```

That assumes you're using unitless line-height values.

Answer (score 0):

The h1 itself is aligned to the simbling element, but the text inside it is not.

To verticaly align the text into a h1 tag you need to set the line height.

```css
.col {
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
.bg {
  background: #333;
}
p,h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.col h1 { 
  line-height: 21px;
}

.col h1 span {
    vertical-align:super;
}

div{
  padding:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col bg"></div>
<div class="col">
  <h1><span>Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title </span></h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

EDIT:

to use it in a multi-line: put your text into a span with a vertical-align:super; The line-height property on h1 will control the space between lines.

Comment: Please read the full question. I have already tried line-height and it does not work for multi-line text, a requirement of any solution.

Comment: what would be your multi-line text?

Comment: A long title. Maybe "This is a Really Long Title That is Likely To Wrap Onto a Second Line, Potentially Causing Line-Height Issues."

Comment: That does work, which is progress. I'm not thrilled about the extra markup though... This solution works then but isn't really applicable to my CMS-driven needs. Thanks.

Comment: I see. According what I've read online, it is not possible to verticaly align the text into a h1 without setting its height/line-height. I think you probably will have to regard on the margins.

Comment: or maybe rely on some JS to wrap the h1 content into a span and use this css idea